# Sublime Text 3 Automatically adds PHP to Ignored Packages

Tags: sublime-text-2

I'm running Sublime Text 3 with the following Packages:

"PHP Companion"
"Package Control",
"PHP Completion"
"PHP Getter and Setter"
"PHP Grammar"
"PHP Snippet"

Everytime I start sublime PHP automatically added to ignored packages like so:

```
"ignored_packages":
[
    "PHP"
    "Vintage"
],
```

I've tried commenting out "PHP" from ignored packages and saving it, as well as deleting it completely from "ignored_packages" and saving it, but then every time I start Sublime up, it puts it back.

Does anyone know what might be causing this error? How could I fix it? If you need any more information, please comment and let me know

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Presumably to avoid conflicts, the *PHP Grammar* package [disables](https://github.com/gerardroche/sublime-php-grammar/blob/99e941a71f00f1b15f3b714111141a64777a0b75/plugin.py#L9) the the default PHP package

Comment: Please accept the answer by clicking the check mark – https://superuser.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 0):

I'm the author of the package. It disables the native PHP package to avoid conflicts.

You don't need to fix anything. That said, php-grammar doesn't provide PHP completions or snippets, those are provided by their separate packages:

- [PHP Completions Kit](https://github.com/gerardroche/sublime-phpck)
- [php-snippets](https://github.com/gerardroche/sublime-php-snippets)